# Indenting or Backspacing with phpDesigner8

Tags: php, phpdesigner

Has anybody seen any documention anywhere about phpDesigner8 where if you highlight a section of code and want to indent it right or left for a quick way to do so instead of going through line by line and backspacing or tabbing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried tab for normal indent and shift+tab for unindent after selecting a block of code, that is.

Comment: Wow the simpliest things I didn't know. I didn't see it anywhere in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, you can also use Ctrl+Shift+I to indent and Ctrl+Shift+U to unindent.